# Iterate through List with range

Tags: python

I'm confused with some python basics. 
I have my list:

```
myList = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

now I would like to print this list using index and range:

```
for i in range(0, len(myList)):
    print(myList[i])
```

I got:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

My first question: Why I shouldn't use len(myList)-1? len(myList) returns 6 but when I use directly print(myList[6]) I got out of range error. Why using this in for loop is different?

Second. I know I can use myList.reverse() but I would like to print reversed list like this:

```
for i in range(len(myList), 0, -1):
    print(myList[i])
```

I get out of range and I should add -1:

```
for i in range(len(myList)-1, 0, -1):
    print(myList[i])
```

but after this I got only:

```
f
e
d
c
b
```

My second question: where is "a"? ;) and why in this example I have to use len(myList)-1?

Comment: `range(0, n)` goes 0, 1, 2, .... n-1 (n not included)

Comment: `range(n, 0, -1)` goes n, n-1, n-2, .... 1 (0 not included). Point is: `range` does not include its end-point.

Comment: Note that idiomatically, one would just use ``for element in myList:`` and ``for element in reversed(myList):``. Likewise, you can just inspect the elements of ``range(len(myList))`` and others by printing ``i``.

Comment: len() function return the number of elements in collections. So if you have 6 elements, it means last index will be 5. That's why you can't use myList[6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things to note:

1. Python is zero-indexed
   This explains the `IndexError` when executing `myList[6]` because the last element is #5 not #6.
2. `range(start, stop)` is "front-inclusive" and "end-exclusive"
   So while iterating, you print `myList[0]` but not `myList[6]`, which is why you did not get an `IndexError` here.
3. `range(n)`
   `n` represents the number of times to execute the for loop, so because you would like to print 6 elements, you should do `range(len(myList))` without `-1`.
4. `range(start, stop, step)`
   Again, Python's for loops are "front-inclusive" and "end-exclusive" so you should start with the index of the last element (`len(myList)-1`) and end with the index of the first element minus 1 (`-1`). Step size can be thought of as the "displacement" while iterating, so with a step size of `-1`, you decrease the iterator `i` by one at each epoch.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Most of which is spelled out in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range)  and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq). If one googles "python range" and looks for official sources, they'll instantly hit https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#func-range which links to these docs.

Answer (score 1):

The first prameter is inclusive, whereas the second parameter is exclusive. Which means if a range function is called like `range(a,b)` it would result in values between `[a,b)`. Therefore when you use `range(0, len(myList))`, this loops through `0..len(myList)-1`.

As you would have guessed by now, you need to subtract `1` while looping in reverse order because the last index of the array is `len(myList) -1` and you are missing `a` because `0` is not included. Therefore, if you wish to iterate in reverse order, you could do `range(len(myList)-1, -1, -1)`.

Comment: Note that in order to iterate a ``range`` in reverse, ``reversed(range(len(myList))`` can be used. This will automatically calculate a new ``range`` with the proper bounds.

Comment: If you are feeling more pythonic, you can also use `myList[::-1]`! :D

Comment: Lists have an optimized reverse iterator as well, so ``reversed(myList)`` should be preferred. ``myList[::-1]`` creates an unnecessary copy.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: It doesn't really create a copy. Slicing usually copies the references to the objects and not the object it self...

Answer (score 1):

First of all know that indexes start from 0 and not 1. When you go for myList[6], first of all, it doesn't exist because index start from 0. If you have 6 elements, the the last index is 5. So, myList[5] is 'f'.
Now, range() works such that when you give arguments as range(0, len(myList)), it iterates from 0 to len(myList)-1. It iterates upto 1 less than the given argument.

For your second question, again you will have to start with len(myList)-1 because last index is 5 in your case. And about where is a, you will have to go till range(len(myList)-1,-1,-1) so that it goes up till 0th index.

Answer (score 1):

First question, why: python works that way, odd at firs but normal when you become used to it. Range[a, b] gives: a, a+1, a+2, ... b-1 (includes the first parameter and excludes the last).

It means that for the second question you should use:

```
for i in range(len(myList)-1, -1, -1):
    print(myList[i])
```